# Error on creating sub domains with Nginx

Tags: nginx

this is my first time working with Nginx, I am trying to create a sub-domain, but once I enter the sub-domain in the browser, I get the error **`This web page is not available :(`**, so I am here for you to help me, please

I have one configuration for mobile which is

```
server {
    large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;

    listen       80;
    server_name  www.the-thing.mobi  the-thing.mobi;
    root   /home/c0pt/things/thingsMobile/www;

    location / {
     index index.html index.htm
     ...
    }
 }
```

and the other for web, which is the one not working

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.desktop.the-thing.mobi  desktop.the-thing.mobi;
    root   /home/c0pt/things/thingsWebApp/dist;

    location / {
     index index.html index.htm
     ...
    }
 }
```

if I enter `www.the-thing.mobi` which is the sub-domain for mobile, everything works, but if I enter `www.desktop.the-thing.mobi`, then the error message **`This web page is not available :(`** comes up.

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the config bellow

```
server {
    large_client_header_buffers 1 1K;

    listen 80;
    server_name  "~^(?<subdomain>[^.]*)\.?the-thing.mobi$"  the-thing.mobi www.the-thing.mobi;


    location / {
     if($subdomain){
      root /home/c0pt/things/thingsWebApp/dist;  
     }
     if ($host = 'the-thing.mobi'|$host = 'www.the-thing.mobi') {
     root /home/c0pt/things/thingsMobile/www;  
     }
     index index.html index.htm
     ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: and what about the configuration for the desktop part ? this part you are asking me to edit, is the part working correctly, the part is not working is the desktop part: ```www.desktop.the-thing.mobi```

Comment: or you are asking me to do this with both server blocks ?

Comment: No just in one block . You might be having problem because your trying to make 2  intance listen to the same port! that's why i transformed it in one block.  you can try to inverse your config to make shure and then let me know i'll edit the response once it's not that.

Comment: so, I have to delete one of my blocks ? or just edit the one for ```www.the-thing.mobi``` without deleting anything ?

Comment: First do this put this first in your conf `server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.desktop.the-thing.mobi  desktop.the-thing.mobi;
    root   /home/c0pt/things/thingsWebApp/dist;

    location / {
     index index.html index.htm
     ...
    }
 }`

and then put the mobile part 


and see if the desktop part work. If it's the case then it means the two can't work at the same time. and do what i suggested. if not do that the config any way it should work .

Comment: that's the way I have that part and it is not working, only the mobile part which is ```www.the-thing.mobi``` is working so far. So, my question again: do I need to delete any of the server blocks and stay only with your suggestion ? or do I implement your suggestion and delete the server block for desktop ?

Comment: Implement my suggestion.

Comment: I am getting this error ```nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($subdomain)"```

Comment: Remove the quote "" arroud the regex to `~^(?<subdomain>[^.]*)\.?the-thing.mobi$`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73876/discussion-between-nietzscheprogrammer-and-skip87).